# Python - Sorting a dictionary {String Key: List of Strings} by len(value)?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Suppose I have the following dictionary:

```
{"A":["u","w"],"B":["t"],"C":["x","y","z"]}
```

How can I sort the dictionary by number of strings in the list in of each value so that it returns:

```
[("C",["x","y","z"]), ("A",["u","w"]), ("B":["t"])]
```

Because the value of "C" has three items in the list, "A" has two, "B" has one. I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
sorted(d.items(),key=operator.methodcaller(len(),tuple[1]),reverse=True)
```

Or

```
sorted(d.items(),key=(string, stringList):(len(stringList),string),reverse=True)
```

But both do not seem to work. Still quite new to sorting, so thanks for the help!

Comment: `operator.methodcaller` takes a string as the first paramater, the method to call, `tuple[1]` doesn't exist at the time you call it. Also `key` is a function, not a tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> d = {"A":["u","w"],"B":["t"],"C":["x","y","z"]}
>>> sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: len(x[1]), reverse=True)
[('C', ['x', 'y', 'z']), ('A', ['u', 'w']), ('B', ['t'])]
```

Comment: That was fast! Thank you jamylak, marking your response as the answer in 11 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it.

```
>>> sorted(d, key=lambda x: len(d[x]), reverse=True)
['C', 'A', 'B']
```

Or, to get the values as well:

```
>>> sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: len(x[1]), reverse=True)
[('C', ['x', 'y', 'z']), ('A', ['u', 'w']), ('B', ['t'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `lambda`:

```
sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: len(x[1]), reverse=True)
```